# How to overcome hover issue in Cypress?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, cypress

I faced Cypress hover problem regarding access to a sub menu appearing after hovering on main menu item. The error is `This element is not visible because it has CSS property: position: fixed and it's being covered by another element:`. I tried to use workarounds recommended by Cypress https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/hover#Workarounds but did not succeed. Cypress documentation says "Using .trigger() will only affect events in JavaScript and will not trigger any effects in CSS", so I tried to change CSS property of the element at first and then use .trigger command:

```
        cy.get('.header-module--subMenu--1TF98.header-module--menuLevel2--2QGyh').eq(0).invoke('attr', 'style', 'position: absolute');
        cy.get('.header-module--subMenu--1TF98.header-module--menuLevel2--2QGyh').eq(0).should('have.attr', 'style', 'position: absolute');
        cy.get('.header-module--subMenu--1TF98.header-module--menuLevel2--2QGyh').eq(0).invoke('show');
        cy.get('.header-module--subMenu--1TF98.header-module--menuLevel2--2QGyh').eq(0).trigger('mouseover');
```

but it did not work. Regardless I have confirmation  `expected <ul.header-module--subMenu--1TF98.header-module--menuLevel2--2QGyh> to have attribute style with the value **position: absolute**` I have the same error on the final step `This element <ul.header-module--subMenu--1TF98.header-module--menuLevel2--2QGyh> is not visible because it has CSS property: **position: fixed** and it's being covered by another element:`. How can I access the hidden submenu without using `{ force: true }` argument?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something might be wrong with the selector, since you set `position: absolute` and confirm it, yet the message still references `position: fixed`.

Assuming the selector is ok, you might be able to trigger the "show" effect with `.realHover()` from [cypress-real-events](https://github.com/dmtrKovalenko/cypress-real-events).

It uses Chrome Devtools Protocol to automate the chrome devtools (only for chrome browser).

Comment: I have installed cypress-real-events package and tried its .realHover() method. An error "cy.get(...).eq(...).realHover is not a function" arose

Comment: Why did you get that error? Other people use it just fine. Please show code used in question.

Comment: Sorry, jus forget to add import "cypress-real-events/support"; into index file. Works fine! Thank you @user16695029

Comment: Thanks for pointing out this lib, I've been having lots of issues with normal events in cy when writing DnD tests.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem like that but u can resolve(works for me) it, see the below steps.

1. install cypress-real-events -> npm i cypress-real-events or npm i cypress-real-events --f.
2. import this statement -> import "cypress-real-events"; into your commands.js or index.js whichever u have in under your support folder.
3. Now use it like this -> cy.get(".cssmenu > :nth-child(1)").realHover();

Hope this will help u guys.